# Inline edit update in datatable for multiple rows in lwc

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have created a lwc where there is a lightning datatable

html code

```html
 <lightning-datatable key-field="Id"
                        data={sObjectRecordList}
                        columns={columns}
                        onsave={handleSave}
                        draft-values={draftValues}>
 </lightning-datatable>
```

js code

```javascript
 @track draftValues = [];
 import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
 import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

 handleSave(event) {
    const recordInputs =  event.detail.draftValues.slice().map(draft => {
        const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
        return { fields };
    });
    const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
    console.log("@@@@@"+JSON.stringify(promises));
    Promise.all(promises).then(contacts => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Contacts updated',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
         // Clear all draft values
         this.draftValues = [];

         // Display fresh data in the datatable
         return refreshApex(this.sObjectRecordList);
    }).catch(error => {
        // Handle error
    });
}
```

once I hit on save in the datatable, I am getting data till the recordInputs map. However, the constant called promise is coming up as empty.

The console is printing the following value :

```
[{},{}]
```

As a result the contact records are not getting updated.

I am using the following reference to create the datatable

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_inline_edit

Comment: (1) That's the default output if you try to stringify a promise. If you simply do a `console.log(promises);`, you can observe `object Promise` in console. (2) Are you sure the data is not saved? I mean have you tried to query the records and observe its values? (3) Is the success toast message displayed? If not, can you write code in the `.catch` block to observe the error details? (4) Have you placed a spinner and activated it while the save txn happens? I remember not being able to see the updated values in the absence of spinner, but it was a while ago and hence, not 100% sure about it.

Comment: @arut 1. I checked that, the promise object is getting printer. 2. I am sure the data is not saved. 3. I queried the backend to check and the previous value was still present. I will try implementing a catch block as well as a spinner.

Comment: I have a few questions, - is the toast message showing up? - is sObjectRecordList property decorated with @track? - did you check using a debugger?